# Дата выводится на английском Битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Подскажите почему выводится дата на английском и как это можно исправить чтобы было на русском?

Пишу `<?=strtolower(FormatDate("d F", MakeTimeStamp($arItem['ACTIVE_FROM'])))?>` выводит 22 june, а не 22 января

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и тут вроде справа должно на русском выводится, например 28 Ноября 2023
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Настройка в списке сайта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Исправить можно с помощью `Loc::setCurrentLang('ru');`. Но я бы ещё посоветовал проверить /bitrix/php_interface/init.php и /local/php_interface/init.php, нет ли там каких-либо операций с переключением языков.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли! Да, тут была проблема /bitrix/php_interface/init.php